# Change package property in AndroidManifest depending on the applicationId in build time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I am trying to create dynamic package names in my .apk during build time. The problem is that i cannot put a place holder in AndroidManifest.xml as system by default exposes `${applicationId}` but this cannot be used.

I cannot also use `manifestPlaceholders = [package:""+ applicationId +""]` specified in the `defaultConfig` in build.gradle.

What i tried to do is:

```
String packageName = System.getProperty("packageName")

defaultConfig {
    applicationId packageName
    minSdkVersion 19
    manifestPlaceholders = [package:""+ packageName +""]
    targetSdkVersion 25
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and the buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            println("Building release apk using application id: " + packageName)
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            println("Building debug apk using application id: " + packageName)
            if (packageName == null) {
                packageName = "com.example.mypackage"
            }
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
    }
```

What i am trying to achieve here is to get the package name from command line and if someone try to build release without specifing it the build to fail. But even though i do not specify and i execute task `assembleRelease` i get this message:

```
Building release apk using application id: null
Building debug apk using application id: null
```

It still builds the apk and it runs completely fine and this is due to the package provided in Manifest. So my question is how do i dynamically change package in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: where do you set `packageName`?

Comment: I did not generate apk file in your way but  here no info about your property https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: i set the package name from command line

Comment: so post your command line here